# How to use if command as an extension of find?

Tags: shell, find

I want to find for some name(s) in directory tree, and when I find specific directory, I want to check if it has some default subdirectory. Problem is, I do not know how to accomplish this. I tried using this command:

```
find -iname $i -exec if [ -d $1/subdir ] then echo $1 fi
```

but then I get report like this:

> find: missing argument to `-exec'

So, what is right solution for this?

Comment: Don't forget the `\;` to end the `-exec` portion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exec` requires a single executable, not an arbitrary shell command. Run a new shell instance explicitly, and pass your shell command as the argument to the `-c` option. Use `{}` as the single positional argument to `sh` so that the name of the found directory is
properly passed to the shell command.

```
find -iname "$i" -exec sh -c 'if [ -d "$1"/subdir ]; then echo "$1"; fi' '{}' \;
```

It might be a little simpler to reorganize your logic, if possible:

```
find -wholename "$i/subdir" -type d -exec dirname '{}' \;
```

This has `find` look for the actual `subdir` directory instead of its parent, then prints the directory name *containing* `subdir`.

Comment: I just approved an edit that should fix the second command, assuming your version of `find` supports `-wholename`.